# Logging CockroachDB queries

Tags: cockroachdb

I have an application running CockroachDB on AWS and want to log all of the queries it executes. However, I can’t find anything in my cluster’s logs that seems to contain the queries. I tried grepping through them for my application’s `SELECT` statements but can’t find them.

Is there a way to enable query logging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer is outdated. There are two mechanisms:

- for regular inspection/troubleshooting, one should use SQL statement execution logging as documented here: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/query-behavior-troubleshooting.html#cluster-wide-execution-logs
- for access audits (when required for e.g. regulation) use audit logging: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/sql-audit-logging.html

Answer (score 1):

When starting a node with cockroach start, include the `--vmodule=executor=2` flag to log all SQL queries. For example:

`cockroach start --background --vmodule=executor=2`

You can access the logs then from the log files stored in `cockroach-data/logs`

If you’re curious about logging queries that run “too long”, set the env var `COCKROACH_TRACE_SQL` to a duration to log all queries longer than that duration.

One can also activate this logging after starting the server by accessing the URL `http://[admin UI URL]/debug/vmodule/executor=2` using the same host/port as the admin UI.

Comment: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/query-behavior-troubleshooting.html#per-node-execution-logs the answer is somewhat outdated. use: 
cockroach start --vmodule=exec_log=2

Comment: The previous answers are out of date. Please check my other answer with links to the CockroachDB docs on query logging.